# Do Rastafarians believe in Jesus as the Way to God?

Tags: christology, rastafarian

Do Rastafarians believe that Jesus is the way to God in the same way that Christians believe? I find that their singing speaks a lot about God and spiritual matters.

Comment: They share **some** beliefs as orthodox Christianity but not all of the beliefs - else they would just be considered orthodox Christians and not have a different title.  Same can be said for other religions.  It's not all cut and dry, else we would not have multiple Christian denominations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, I think it's necessary to point out that Christianity is not defined by being a "lot about God and other spiritual matters". Most world religions could include this. You could just as easily be Muslim and [sing a lot about a god and spiritual matters](https://youtu.be/ZKJ3qUHJPaI).

Even more specifically than that, a group may have a set of beliefs that draw on many common themes from Christianity without being Christian. Such is the case with the Rastafari Movement. It is a philosophy and loosely organized way of life that includes some common themes and often reuses terms and phrases found in Christianity, but at it's core is a completely separate set of beliefs.

To directly answer your question, no Rastafarians do not believe that Jesus is the way to God in the same way that the majority of Christians (of any major tradition) do. In fact they believe the Christian scriptures have been [corrupted](http://altreligion.about.com/od/alternativereligionsaz/a/rastafari.htm). Being a loosely organized set of beliefs it is important to note that you might run into a few people who do believe in Jesus and claim to be Rastafarian. However the [normative Rastafari beliefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastafari#World-views_and_doctrines) are quite different.

They do not hold the same beliefs about sin, the reasons for our separation from God or the only solution to that problem. They are usually willing to credit Jesus with being a good moral teacher and admire his rebel tendencies, but they completely miss the main point of who he was: God in the flesh and the **only** incarnate Messiah.

That last bit is important, because they typically do believe in a "christ" or "messiah", but they believe he had another name, took a body at another time, etc. See [Haile Selassie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haile_Selassie#Rastafari_messiah), Emperor of Ethiopia, to whom Rastafarians attribute many of the things found in Christian scriptures rather than to Jesus Christ.

Confusingly, you might even hear "trinity" nomenclature being used by Rastafarians, but be aware that they mean something completely different by this than Christians:

> Rastafari doctrines concerning the Trinity include stressing the significance of the name "Haile Selassie," meaning power of the Trinity, might of the Trinity, powerful trinity in Ge'ez or also Haile Selassie I (qedamawi Haile Selassie) meaning the (first power of the Trinity) name given to Ras Tafari upon his baptism and later assumed as part of his regnal name at his November 2, 1930 coronation by the Ethiopian Orthodox Tewahedo Church, then known as just the Ethiopian Tewahedo Church. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastafari#The_Trinity))

Comment: I take on-board your first paragraph and agree 100% with you. So am I correct in thinking that Haile Selassie is a saviour to the Rastafari movement in the same way as Jesus is our Saviour?

Comment: @user2572 I wouldn't say they see him in exactly "the same way" as they see him more as a hero/leader figure whereas Christ is to us a savior because he gave himself up as a ransom for us, not be because he led some great revolution but because he became a sacrifice to take away our sins. Rastafarian views on Haile Selassie seem to be varied and include him being another incarnation of Christ, but the sense in which that makes him savior is quite different. They don't look to him as the propitiation of their sins (like I said in my answer sin their view on sin itself is radically different).

Comment: "...they mean something completely different by this than Christians."  May I suggest **orthodox** Christians?  Mormons and others may take issue with this.  Following your logic, they wouldn't be Christian either.

Comment: @Dan That would be pointless and make the answer less accurate. I left that particular reference unqualified specifically because it is unnecessary to do so. Mormons, JW's and even much more fringe cults would join orthodox Christians in objecting to the Rastafarian idea of trinity.

Comment: @Dan Also relevant is the fact that the group in question typically does not claim to be Christian in the way that, for example, Mormons do. Hence it is unnecessary to find a PC label that avoids excluding them here. Mormons on the other hand claim to be true Christianity, hence the host of issues in labeling them. I did qualify another statement higher up that would not have been quite so universally applicable.

Comment: @DanAndrews What point is there in using words if you intentionally render them meaningless by your context? While the word cult can have several definitions depending on who's using it, orthodox cult vs non orthodox cult just makes no sense at all. I have already specifically delineated "major traditions" in my answer where some cults are likely excluded and specifically left off the delineation for the statements that I know even most non-mainstream cults would agree with.

Comment: @TheFreemason Just to add to the confusion -- When you say Orthodox in this context, it appears that you mean Trinitarian, not Orthodox with a big O, as in the Eastern Orthodox sect. On another note, Mormons are not Trinitarian.

Comment: @Caleb Just to add to the confusion -- When you say Orthodox in this context, it appears that you mean Trinitarian, not Orthodox with a big O, as in the Eastern Orthodox sect. On another note, Mormons are not Trinitarian. I believe Freemason is using cult interchangeably with sect.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen I didn't use big "O", I used small "o" on purpose.  Secondly, yes, I used "cult" by its true definition, not it's connotation.  Thirdly, this is a rather old comment thread and should just be deleted.

Comment: @Caleb *but the sense in which that makes him (Haile Selassie) savior is quite different* -- more similar to the Messiah *a la* David that the Jews of Jesus' time were expecting/hoping for. (per your _Sep 5 '13 at 13:16_ comment)

Answer (score 12):

As a Rasta, I feel led to point out some things. First of all, to answer the question, some Rastas recognize Yeshua (Jesus) as their lord and savior, and see Selassie I as one who continues the work of Christ, through the line of David.

Revelations references Yeshua telling His people of a man that God would send to Earth to continue His work. Rastas believe that man to be Haile Selassie I. Some Rastas see Selassie as God, some as Christ incarnate, and some simply as a prophet who continued God's work on Earth.

Rastafari should not be compared to Christianity, Islam, or Judaism, b/c Rastafari is a livity, not an organized religion, and there are Rastas who follow these faiths.  Christianity in the West is not pure Christianity, but Chaldean Christianity.  This form of Christianity was taken from it's original home in East Africa and "remade" to serve political purposes of the Roman empire, and later Western European societies. It is very political, and very far from the teachings of Christ.

Rastas denounce Chaldean principles, and advocate consciousness and righteous living, through love, respect, and unity of God's people. I personally feel that some Rastas are lost and confused about what righteous living means, but then, I feel the same way about many who call themselves "Christian", "Jewish", or "Muslim" too.

Answer (score 3):

I Have been a Rasta for over 20 yrs and will try to explain our beliefs.

It is correct to say all Rasta's do not believe the samething, but as said which way of life does. Rastafari began in the 1930's with the first Rasta, Leonard Howell preaching of Haile Selassie as the returned Christ. It was not until the 1960's that Rasta's began to separate into different branches or mantions and different beliefs.

So to the question do all Rasta's belief in jesus Christ. Short answer. Some do and some do not.

#### Explanation.

Some rasta mainly the Bobo ashanti do not accept jesus christ or the trinity of the bible. Bobo accept their leader Charles Edwards as the Black christ who showed them their way of life, marcus garvey the prophet who prophecied of Haile Selassie and Haile Selassie who the declare as the almighty.

The Nyabinghi and twelve Tribe accept Haile Selassie as The christ return or the second coming. I am of this way of thought. We were taught that christ is the son of God or the mighty God, christ was called the lamb (isaiah ch 58. But after his crucifixion, resurrection and ascension to heaven he was now called the conquering Lion of the Tribe of Judah (Rev ch.5). One of Haile Selassie titles. Acts ch.2 v. 29-32 says God promised King David the second King of Israel that he would raise up Christ according to the flesh to sit on Davids Throne. The lamb did not do this. To rasta's this prophecy was about the second coming and to rastas Haile Selassie fulfilled this.

So we see Selassie and Christ as the same God manifesting at different time for different reasons. Though not all Rasta's believe the same. This is the view held by the founders and those who are well read and live the way of life.

However I must point out though we accept Christ no Rasta accepts the word Jesus. Jesus is a greek name. Christ real name is Yashua it was changed to jesus when christianity got to Greece. Rasta's ask the Question if the angel told Mary to name her son Yashua, by this name all men will be saved, Why would you change his name.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Selassie said himself that he was not christ and selassie him self was christian. if you want to know rastas opinions about selassie check out the peter tosh album: I am that I am. there he talks about jesusu in one of the interviews. listen if you are interested.

My point here was that i know that many Rastas belive different things about Jesus and christianity, but if you are a true Rastafari then you must listen to Selassie and he was indeed christian 
check it out:
http://www.rastafarispeaks.com/cgi-bin/forum/archive1/config.pl?md=read;id=47396

Comment: Could you expand a bit on *why* this is relevant? Maybe link to the album and include some relevant lyrics?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This site is built on a strict question and answer format. Answers need to sufficiently answer the question without the reader having to go elsewhere. Wax eagle gives a good suggestion on a way to do this, jumping from what you have already given. Click edit under your post to add more content.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question at all. Maybe the external link does, but we expect at least a summary here that states what the answer is to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

What an awesome answer Ras!! I struggle everyday to make of what I know to be true.  I came to the Lord many years ago (19) and grew in the knowledge and faith of Jesus Christ knowing and feeling something was still missing.  Rasta Livity is the true way and it can be different for everyone but I truly believe with my whole heart that it is a blessed manifestation by God, the Most High, to show us in Modern Babylon how we are meant to live.  If you know the Bible, His-tory, and have discernment, you will know that we are living in the exact same situation as in Babylon and for us who have had our culture and identity stripped from us, this path has given us all of that which was taken from us...you dont have to have locks and profess "Jah Rastafari" as Lord and Savior like modern Christians do about Jesus...its deeper than that.  Jah is the name of God in the original King James Version that was somehow removed, and it is the only name of God that is used solely by Rastas.  The meaning of the name Ras Tafari has much symbolism and deeply rooted in ancient Christianity and for those of us "followers of the Way" seeking the pure, narrow way or "pure" Christianity, all we have is Ethiopia to look at, for many reasons.  THe livity is the Life we are here to live and live abundantly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)  Also, this doesn't really answer the question. It looks like it should be a comment on another post, but you haven't yet earned enough to leave comments.  (Again, see the help page.)  Hopefully, soon!

Answer (score 1):

Some might, although these some do not strictly follow Rastafarian writing alone. Many Rastafarians who claim that Jesus is the only way to heaven imply this belief from other situations in their lives. This belief, in particular, does not come from being a Rastafarian... although it does not contradict it - if that makes any sense.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has ***nothing*** to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)